# Setting xrange in gnuplot producing strange result

Tags: csv, gnuplot

I was trying to use gnuplot to graph a CSV file containing date-time and temperature but it was producing some strange results when it worked (mainly just one line straight up in the middle of the graph).  This is the code:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s'
set xrange["2013-05-29 00:00:00":"2013-06-04 00:00:00"]
set datafile separator ','
plot 'weather.csv' using 1:2
```

This is a sample of the data:

```
2013-05-29 18:30:00,20.0
2013-05-29 21:29:00,14.0
2013-05-29 22:29:00,13.0
2013-05-29 23:29:00,12.0
2013-05-30 08:28:00,13.0
2013-05-30 09:30:00,14.0
```

It was getting an error:

```
Can't plot with an empty x range!
```

So I typed the commands at the command line:

```
gnuplot> set xdata time
gnuplot> set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%s'
gnuplot> set xrange["2013-05-29 00:00:00":"2013-06-04 00:00:00"]
gnuplot> show xrange

        set xdata time
        set xrange [ "1970-01-01 00:00:-946684800" : "1970-01-01 00:00:-946684800" ] noreverse nowriteback

gnuplot> show
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your `timefmt` definition.
According to [this documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node274.html), `%s` is interpreted as

```
seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC)
```

This explains the output from your `show xrange` as well. For this date interpretation, your `xrange` will come up empty.

If you use `%S` (`second, 0-60`) instead, your example will plot fine:

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I feel like a dumb bunny!

Comment: @PhilipKearns Don't. Stuff like that happens to all of us all the time.